# parse.com swift - does not have a member getUserObjectWithId

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I need to save an object into Parse with pointer to User table.

At first I try to get PFUser object by objectId

```
var query = PFUser.query()
var user = query.getUserObjectWithId(a.id)
```

or try that

```
var user = PFUser.getUserObjectWithId(a.id)
```

and got the mistake "does not have a member getUserObjectWithId"

Parse API:

```
+ (PFUser *)getUserObjectWithId:(NSString *)objectId
```

And one more question. Is there a simple way to put the pointer to User table without an additional query?

I've try to save earlier PFUser object from query

```
var query = PFUser.query()
query.whereKey("email", equalTo:friendMail)
var friend = query.findObjects()
```

but the result of query is not PFUser.

Answer (score 1):

The answer at the second question:

The object could be saved as PFUser as

```
friend = object as? PFUser
```

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this issue for myself. Try this:

```
var user = PFQuery.getUserObjectWithId(a.id)!
```

In my own project, I was able to use the following successfully:

```
let sampleId:String = "abcXYZ"
let sampleUser:PFUser = PFQuery.getUserObjectWithId(sampleId)!
```